# Access JSON field of join table with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

One shop `has_many` products and a product `belongs_to` a shop.
The shop has `opening_hours` and `closing_hours` columns. Each column stores a hash which looks like the following:

```
opening_hours = {'Monday' => '12:00', 'Tuesday' => '13:00'}
```

and so on

I am working with current date and time, and **I would like to retrieve all products which stores have `opening_hours` smaller than current time which is smaller than `closing_hours`.**
Basically all the products that are available when the shop is open.

I did something like that in my controller:

```
day_today = Date.today.strftime('%A')
time_now = Time.new.strftime('%H:%M')
@products = Product.joins(shop: [{opening_hours[day_today] < time_now, 
                                 {closing_hours[day_today] > time_now }])
```

**Edit**

This is the code that stores the opening times in the DB

```
hours_table = shop.search('table')
    opening_hours = {}
    closing_hours = {}
    hours_table.first.search('tr').each do |tr|
      cells = tr.search('td')
      day = cells.first.text.strip
      hours = cells.last.text.strip.tr('-', '').split
      opening_hours[day] = hours[0].to_time.strftime('%H:%M')
      closing_hours[day] = hours[1].to_time.strftime('%H:%M')
    end

shop = Shop.new(
        name: shop_name,
        opening_hours: opening_hours,
        closing_hours: closing_hours
      )
      shop.save

      new_product = Product.new(
        name: foo,
        description: foo,
        price: foo,
        company: 'foo',
      )
      new_product.shop = shop
      new_product.save
```

This is the migration to add opening hours to Shop. The same is done for closing hours.

```
class AddOpeningHoursToShop < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :shops, :opening_hours, :json, default: {}
  end
end
```

This is the migration to add the shop ID to products

```
class AddShopToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :products, :shop, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Any guess?

Comment: How are the opening and closing hours actually stored in the database? As timestamps for each day? As strings? What about weekends or holidays? Do you take them into account?

Comment: In the code I added above I convert them as time but they appear like strings in the terminal: {"Monday" => "12:00", "Tuesday" => "13:00"}

Comment: Do you have examples of those records? How are the migrations for Product and Shop defined?

Comment: Just added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `->>` operator to access a specific JSON field as text:

```
SELECT opening_hours->>'Monday' AS monday_opening_hour FROM shops;
```

Same for `closing_hours`, it just changes the name of the column and field.

So the AR representation in your case would be like:

```
Product
  .joins(:shop)
  .where(
    "shops.opening_hours->>:day <= :now AND shops.closing_hours->>:day >= :now",
    day: day_today,
    now: time_now
  )
```

You can easily bind the key name and the time you're going to ask for, here as `day` and `now`.

Notice, it's not needed to explicitly prepend the table name, but I'm doing so just for the sake of clarity.

---

This can also be done with the BETWEEN operator:

```
Product
  .joins(:shop)
  .where(
    ":now BETWEEN shops.opening_hours->>:day AND shops.closing_hours->>:day",
    day: day_today,
    now: time_now
  )
```

You can use the one you think is more clear.

In any case, you can get rid of storing the `time_now` variable, by using the `NOW` function of PostgreSQL. It'll handle the time format difference if you cast it to text (`NOW()::text`):

```
Product
  .joins(:shop)
  .where(
    "NOW()::text BETWEEN shops.opening_hours->>:day AND shops.closing_hours->>:day",
    day: day_today
  )
```

Similarly, the day can also be obtained from `NOW`. You can use `to_char(NOW(), 'Day')` for that

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'Day') AS day
FROM generate_series (NOW() - '6 days'::interval, NOW(), '1 day') date;

    day
-----------
 Thursday
 Friday
 Saturday
 Sunday
 Monday
 Tuesday
 Wednesday
```

So:

```
Product
  .joins(:shop)
  .where("NOW()::text BETWEEN shops.opening_hours->>(to_char(NOW(), 'Day'))
                          AND shops.closing_hours->>(to_char(NOW(), 'Day'))")
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! From all the solutions only the first one worked for me. The third one made my terminal glitch and the last one returned an empty array. But thanks again, really appreciate it :))